# Azure Function in Node.js and shared files

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-functions

I am deploying my Azure Functions through a  Bitbucket CI. I am able to reference files from a shared directory in multiple functions which is great.

However, when I try to update my shared code and deploy it by pushing to my master branch, I can see the files being updated in my Kudu console, but my functions themselves still appear to have a reference to the old version of the file... I don't have this problem if I turn off my CI.

Any idea what the problem could be and how to work around this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can specify that your custom shared directories should be monitored for changes by adding them to a `watchDirectories` array in your `host.json` file:

```
{
    "watchDirectories": [ "Shared" ]
}
```

The runtime will then monitor files in those directories for changes, and restart/reload as necessary. Note that monitoring for a top level `node_modules` directory is configured by default.

Comment: I tried this and it doesn't seem to work. I tried a simple shared module returning a number (1), I changed the number in the shared code (2) but the redeployed function is still returning the original number (1)... https://github.com/Schaemelhout/azure-function-ci

Comment: Yes, I just confirmed that there is a bug here :( I've logged an issue [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/issues/954). We'll get a fix out for this in the next few days.

Comment: The fix is already live as noted in the release notes [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/releases/tag/v1.0.10635)

Comment: Ok, not sure how I missed it :) thanks! awesome work.