# How to share code in JavaScript Azure Functions?

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure, mongoose, azure-functions

How can I share code (e.g. Mongo schema definitions) between files in an Azure function app?

I need to do this, as my functions require access to a shared mongo schema and models, such as this basic example:

```
var blogPostSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  id: 'number',
  title: 'string',
  date: 'date',
  content: 'string'
});

var BlogPost = mongoose.model('BlogPost', blogPostSchema);
```

I've tried to add a `"watchDirectories": [ "Shared" ]` line to my `host.json` and in that folder added an `index.js` containing the above variable definition but this doesn't seem to be available to the other functions.

I simply get a `Exception while executing function: Functions.GetBlogPosts. mscorlib: ReferenceError: BlogPost is not defined`.

I've also tried explitely `require`ing the .js file, but this seems not to be found. It could be I just got the path wrong.

Does anyone have an example or tips on how to share `.js` code between azure functions?

Comment: The error would appear to be elsewhere since it's likely that `BlogPost` is actually a symbol pointing to the "Model" rather than the "Schema" definition. Also I doubt you can use mongoose in that way with Azure functions, since I'm "presuming" the supported functionality would be limited to just the "Schema" itself. See [Mongoose in the browser](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/browser.html).

Comment: Hi Neil, you're right the BlogPost var is a reference to the model. However, if I put the schema and model in a single Azure function things work how I'm expecting, but if I then add the schema and model to a second function I get an error from mongoose `Cannot overwrite 'BlogPost' model once compiled` so I'm try to find a way I can define the schema and model once and re-use it

Comment: That is basically my thinking. Have not personally played around enough with Azure functions to be certain, so still on the tuit list. Unless they can actually spin up a full node instance and persist ( which I don't think is the point ) then I don't see such a thing working. Hard to tell without seeing the whole context.

Comment: See below, managed to fix it with some minor tweaking

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I fixed this issue by doing the following steps:

1. Add a line to the root `hosts.json` to `watch` a shared folder. `"watchDirectories": [ "Shared" ]`
2. In the shared folder, added a `blogPostModel.js` file containing the following schema/model definition and export

**shared\blogPostModel.js**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var blogPostSchema = new Schema({
    id: 'number',
    title: 'string',
    date: 'date',
    content: 'string'
});
module.exports = mongoose.model('BlogPost', blogPostSchema);
```

3. In my function `require` the shared file with the following path:
   `var blogPostModel = require('../Shared/blogPostModel.js');`

I can then make a connection and interact with the model doing `find`s etc in each individual function.

This solution was composed from the following SO posts:

[Azure Function in Node.js and shared files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40683516/azure-function-in-node-js-and-shared-files)

[Cannot overwrite model once compiled Mongoose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19051041/cannot-overwrite-model-once-compiled-mongoose)

Comment: Thanks! If you add "watchDirectories": [ "shared" ] and Create a 'shared' directory, azure functions will recognize it